# T-SQL Rank() with condition

Tags: sql-server

My query has the following structure:

```
    Value 1  Value 2
    100%         500
     90%         300
     89%         800
     95%         400
```

I need to rank the results by value 2, but only if value 1 is >= 95%.

How can I do that? I tried to solve the problem using:

```
CASE WHEN [Value 1] >= 95% 
THEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Value 2] DESC)
END
```

The function displays `NULL` for the rows that don't meet the condition, but the ranking sequence increments even on the blank rows.

```
    Value 1  Value 2  Ranking
     89%         800  NULL
    100%         500  2
     95%         400  3
     90%         300  NULL
```

The correct result should be:

```
        Value 1  Value 2  Ranking
         89%         800  NULL
        100%         500  1
         95%         400  2
         90%         300  NULL
```

No ranking for the first and the last item, because both are worse than 95%, the others should be shown according to their rank.

Comment: Can you paste the result you're trying to get for this sample? It's a bit hard to understand the requirement (for me, at least)

Comment: Will you place your sql code and schema in your question please. There is also SQLFiddle that is pretty good at displaying your test info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `PARTITION BY` to your `RANK()` function, as in the following:

```
SELECT 
    v1, 
    v2, 
    CASE 
        WHEN v1 >= 95 
        THEN RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CASE WHEN v1 >= 95 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
            ORDER BY v2 DESC) 
      END AS Ranking
FROM (VALUES (100, 500), (90, 300), (89,800), (95,400)) AS Value(v1, v2)
```

The reason for this is that the `RANK()` function is looking at all rows returned by the query, not just the ones evaluated by the `CASE` expression. By adding the same expression to the `PARTITION BY`, this will in effect rank the rows in two distinct groups, those that meet your condition (`>= 95`) and those that do not.

This exposes the ranking as you intend.

Comment: Super! Many thanks, it finally works! Although I can't really understand why I have to start with a case when, and then add a second (same) Separation by using PARTITION.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a bit non-intuitive: it is essentially because the windowed function is calculated against the entire resultset, not just those values returned by the CASE expression.  Still, glad you got it working! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and have fun!

Comment: I like this Answer!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the result you want for the values that are less than 95%, you could try something like this.  May need to tweak it a little depending on how your `Value1` is stored.

```
case when value1 > 95 then 
     rank() over (order by case when Value1 > 95 then 1 else 100 end
                  , Value2)
end
```

This will cause the lower values to be sorted to the bottom of your ranking.

Comment: @user3066469 - did not see your comment below initially (users are only notified of comments if you correctly spell their name or reply to their post).  I have modified my response to convert the undesirable values back to nulls.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating your question with your desired output...  The below will do it:

```
;With Ranking as (
    SELECT  v1, v2, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY v2 DESC) as Ord
    FROM (VALUES (1.00, 500), (.90, 300), (.89,800), (.95,400)) AS Value(v1, v2)
)
select  r.v1, r.v2, case when v1 >= .95 then r.Ord end Ord
from    Ranking r
order by r.Ord;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: <p>@AHP: I tried your solution, but unfortunately it doesn't help to put the bad values to the end,
<p>@Kevin: it doesn't help either not to Show the bad values. The reason is the following:

I did the following:
      --, CASE WHEN
VALUE1 >=0.95     
THEN
RANK() OVER
(ORDER BY VALUE2)
ELSE    -- 
'9999'
END
AS RANG

When I get the ranking it contains gaps (for those values <95%). But I need a ranking that totally skips those values.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your desired output.  Hope it helps.